# Split PostgreSQL Query filtering

Tags: postgresql, split

I want to filter the course matery is taken by students, my data like this.

```
select * from course;
```

**And show data like this**

```
+----+-------+----------+-------+
| id | name  | idcourse | status|
+----+-------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Udin  | 1, 5, 8  |    OK |
|  2 | Udin  | 2, 4, 1  |    OK |
|  3 | Mamat |    1, 8  |    OK |
+----+-------+----------+-------+
```

how to perform the query? 
example

```
select * from course where idcourse=8;
```

and will display the record 1 and 3.

Comment: Why would you put idcourse in the student table? Why not work with a link-table that links students and courses?

Comment: The best way to solve this, if it lies within your control (i.e. if you have access to the database model) is to save the course IDs in a separate table, one row per entry per student, and then use a JOIN.

Comment: What's the type of the idcourse column? Varchar?

Comment: yeah idcourse is varchar

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from course
where '8' = any (string_to_array(replace(idcourse,' ',''), ','))
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: can you let me know whether the function 'any' is supported in 8.1 version ?

Comment: @AashMaharoon: no idea. 8.1 is extremely old and has not been supported for ages. You shouldn't be using it. Updgrade to 9.x **now**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I tried it. It works well. :) . Thanks for your answer.