# Postgres split as it can be used for IN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use Postgres 8.1. In my sub function I am returning a string which some ID s are concatenated together. And I need to split those ID s and use them in the `WHERE` clause from main select query.

for example sub function:

```
subFunction( 'item_id' character varying )RETURNS character varying AS
-- implementation of sub function--- 

return concatenatedString;
```

this concatenatedString like this: 23|32|25|234.

And in my main query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN (--need to get ids returning from sub function splitting the string--) .
```

Is there any way that I can split the string returned by sub function and put the result into the `IN` clause.

**Another approach to solve this :** [Split PostgreSQL Query filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083943/split-postgresql-query-filtering)

Comment: Can you change the output of the function from a concatenated string to a set returning function?

Comment: Also you really should not being using version 8.1, it's no longer supported. If you were on a supported version like at least 8.4 you could use select regexp_split_to_table('a|b|c|d', E'\\|').

Comment: @JustBob : thanks for reply. I am not clear that about 'set' and how I can implement it. I do not need exactly a concatenated string, but need to get done the job. Also I have to stick with this 8.1 version.

Comment: Are you really using PostgreSQL 8.1? Or are you actually using Greenplum, Redshift, ParAccel, or some fork like that? If you're on 8.1 then you _must_ update sooner or later, there's no effort being made to ensure that 8.1 supports new operating system releases etc. The update will only get (much) more painful as time goes on.

Comment: Another approach to solve this is here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083943/split-postgresql-query-filtering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JustBob says in his comments, your best bet would be to upgrade to a more recent postgresql version, after which you could use regexp_split_to_table, or regexp_split_to_array and then use array operators instead, eg.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = ANY (regexp_split_to_array(subFunction(...), '\|'));
```

However, luckily for you, your string resembles an alternation regex, so you might just be able to get away with this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id::text ~ '^(' || subFunction(...) || ')$';
```

This will do a regular expression match against a regex looking like this

```
^(23|32|25|234)$
```

which will return true if your id value is in the list.

That should work even in 8.1.